# Get form values in semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, redux, semantic-ui-react

Here is my form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const CreatePostForm = ({ onSubmit }) =>
  <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <Form.Input name='user' label='user' placeholder='Enter user name' />
    <Form.Input name='title' label='title' placeholder='Enter post title' />
    <Form.Input name='text' label='text' placeholder='Enter post text' />
    <Form.Input name='category' label='category' placeholder='Enter post category' />
    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
  </Form>

export default CreatePostForm
```

It is then connected:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import CreatePostForm from '../components/CreatePostForm.jsx'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
  return {
    onSubmit: (e, data) => {
      console.log(e)
      console.log(data)
    },  
  }
} 

const ConnectedCreatePostForm = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CreatePostForm)
export default ConnectedCreatePostForm
```

In `onSubmit` I expect some data to be passed that would allow me to retrieve each input form field value by `name` but I can't access it somehow: there is `event` and `data` (I would hope for) which is just the form itself not really `data`. How to access the values upon submission? I don't want to handle state and want my component - `CreatePostForm`  - to stay dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to get the data from the inputs for the form directly:

```
Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target))
```

will give you an object made from the data of the form. (Note [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is a somewhat newer API. There's a lodash method: [fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs) that is functionally identical if needed)

Edit: If you need to use lodash's fromPairs: you'll need to do as follows, as lodash's fromPairs doesn't automatically go over the FormData as an iterator:

```
fromPairs(Array.from(new FormData(target)))
```

You could also grab the values directly from the form element by the input name:

```
console.log(event.target.user.value);
```

This will allow you to be able to use the form without having to set it up as controlled components.

Example below. I didn't include Semantic in the example because this is vanilla JS.

```js
const CreatePostForm = () =>{
  const onSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const {target} = event;
    console.log('FormData', Object.fromEntries(new FormData(target)));
    console.log('target.user.value', target.user.value);
  }
  return <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <input name='user' label='user' placeholder='Enter user name' />
    <input name='title' label='title' placeholder='Enter post title' />
    <input name='text' label='text' placeholder='Enter post text' />
    <input name='category' label='category' placeholder='Enter post category' />
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<CreatePostForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: yes confirmed, you can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-test-nq03m?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: For me `target.user.value` works, but `new FormData(target)` produces an empty object, not sure why..

Comment: I think thats because we need to loop through the obtained `FormData` and `Object.fromEntries` works, but `lodash` `fromPairs` does not.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko, I updated with a bit of instruction on how to get fromPairs to work. Essentially you just need to convert FormData to an array. `Array.from` works well for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Semantic UI React as designed, it appears you must use controlled components, so your hope of not using state doesn't seem feasible.

### Semantic UI React Example

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#usage-capture-values

And the tip just above the section:

> Our `<Form />` handles data just like a vanilla React . See React's [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) docs for more.